# Set properties to jsf managed-bean

Tags: jsf, properties, set, managed-bean

Have following first .jsf:

```
<ui:repeat var="prod" value="#{showProducts.decoys}">
     <h:form>
       {prod.price} 
       {prod.weight} 
       {prod.size} >
    <h:commandButton value="Buy" action="shoppingCart"/>
    </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

Have following shoppingCart.jsf:

```
<h:form>
 <h:dataTable value="#{prod}">
  <h:column>
   #{prod.name}<br/>
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
   #{prod.price}<br/>
  </h:column>
  <h:column>        
   <h:inputText value="#{prod.count}" size="3"/>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>  
<h:inputText value="#{order.phone}"/><br/>
<h:inputText value="#{order.mail}"><br/>
<h:inputText value="#{order.city}"/><br/>
<h:commandButton value="Order" action="#{showProducts.persistOrder}">
</h:form>
```

Faces-config:

```
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>showProducts</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>main.ShowProducts</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
...
            <managed-property>
               <property-name>product</property-name>
               <value>#{product}</value>
            </managed-property>
        </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>product</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>main.Product</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
...
```

The problem:
managed bean name defined as `product`
iteration goes this way(shoppingCart.jsf): 
`h:dataTable value="#{prod}">`
so it means that this iteration is not connected with bean named `product` anyhow

How to set properties `prod.price,prod.weight,prod.count` to real managed bean properties:

```
product.price,product.weight,product.size
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You aren't setting a specific `prod` in the session scoped bean. You should do this.

   ```
   <h:commandButton value="Buy" action="shoppingCart">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{showProducts.product}" value="#{prod}" />
   </h:commandButton>
   ```

   By the way, the `managed-property` declaration only sets an new/empty bean as property during parent bean's ceration. This is not necessarily the **same** `prod` instance as you have in the `ui:repeat`. You can just remove the `#{product}` bean from your `faces-config.xml`.
2. The `h:dataTable` doesn't make any sense here. You need `h:panelGrid` here.

   ```
   <h:panelGrid columns="3">
       <h:outputText value="#{showProducts.product.name}" />
       <h:outputText value="#{showProducts.product.price}" />
       <h:outputText value="#{showProducts.product.count}" />
   </h:panelGrid>
   ```

Comment: BalusC,thanks a lot. It works.I dodn't even know about <f:setPropertyActionListener.Shoud read manuals more.